# How to type special character on ubuntu

Tags: special-characters

A bit silly, but I can't type this character ಠ, on ubuntu.

Some page say it should be this way

```
Ctrl+Shift type u0CA0
```

But it doesnt do anything. Even I find a shortcut for sublime that I didn't know that exist before try this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> all together, and an underline will appear under the *u*, then you type the hexadecimal value for the Unicode character, and then press Space or Enter to confirm it.

Comment: Worth mentioning the following: (1) after pressing Ctrl + Shift + U, release all three keys before typing your UNICODE sequence, (2) the hexadecimal code should be all lowercase i.e. `U0ca0` rather than `U0CA0` and (3) you can leave out leading zeroes i.e. `Uca0` is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

1. Install gucharmap (GNOME [Unicode] Character Map), if it is not already installed
2. Run gucharmap
3. Select "Kannada" under Unicode Block
4. Find the character(s) you want, double click on each of them; they appear in "text to copy"
5. Click on the "copy" button to put them into the paste buffer
6. Paste into the document or file where you want the character(s) to appear

[image]